# Need to understand SONY lifelog API

Tags: sony-lifelog-api

How does sony-lifelog API functionality works offline? As API need to respond with data available at its end which is not stored in device locally as well how does this mechanism works. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The API does not work offline actually. If you need access to historical data you will have to store it locally and then access it later.